# Merge rows in Pandas dataframe based on content, with multi-column grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, bigdata

I have a data frame in Python's Pandas with the following format;

```
|-------------------------------|
|person | month | day | am | pm |
|-------------------------------|
|    A  |   5   | 10  | 1  | 0  |
|    B  |   5   | 10  | 1  | 0  |
|    A  |   5   | 12  | 0  | 1  |
|    B  |   5   | 12  | 1  | 0  |
|-------------------------------|
```

In this dummy example, I have data on 2 people (called "A" and "B") who work either an AM slot or a PM slot. Therefore, each row contains the person's label (A or B), the month and day as two columns, and then a binary value in AM and PM columns to indicate if they worked (1) or not (0).

I want to convert this dataframe into a different format, where each month & day pair have only one row, and the person label is now included by creating new columns, as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------
month | day | A_am | A_pm | B_am | B_pm |
-----------------------------------------
   5  | 10  |  1   |   0  |   1  |  0   |
   5  | 12  |  0   |   1  |   1  |  0   |
-----------------------------------------
```

How can this be done please? I've seen related questions use tools such as dataframe.agg and groupby, but I'm not sure how to adapt this for my case. I think I need to group by both "month" and "day" columns, then somehow create new columns?

Any help greatly welcomed - thanks.

Please note, this is a dummy example and in my real-world use case, the two columns to group by are not month and day (i.e. not part of a date). Therefore, I'm interested in a general solution for arbitrary dtypes of month & day, not something that converts them into a single date format. I also have big datasets, so performance is important and I'd like to avoid slow loops.